fail2ban filter works but IP not banned
I have fail2ban filter set up to scan error.log
Messages are in this format:
[Sun Apr 21 12:37:02.266167 2024] [:error] [pid 26113:tid 139778838230784] [client 197.91.24.227] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "/login" at REQUEST_URI. [file "/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf"] [line "110"] [id "800000"] [msg "login"] [hostname "www.mysite.com"] [uri "/user/login"] [unique_id "ZiUIbn8AAQEAAGYBe@cAAADE"]

Failregex is failregex = ^.*\[client <HOST>\] ModSecurity: Warning\. Pattern match \"\/login\".*
When testing using fail2ban-regex SKerror.log mymodsecurity.conf  Im getting
Results
=======

Failregex: 1254 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [1254] ^.*\[client <HOST>\] ModSecurity: Warning\. Pattern match \"\/login\".*
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [3052] {^LN-BEG}(?:DAY )?MON Day %k:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: ExYear)?
`-

I put this to my jail
[mymodsecurity]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = mymodsecurity
logpath  = /var/www/*/log/*error.log
maxretry = 15

However fail2ban does not ban IP addresses. can this be because it can not read time format in error log? Or where can be the problem? Thank you
